# How to change input device for Android Voice Access (Accessibility)?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, accessibility, bluetooth-audio, voice

I am running Lineage OS v20, my device is rooted OnePlus 7.
I want to use my Bluetooth device as an input for the Voice Access, but it doesn't work.
I tried changing audio_policy_configuration.xml by adding BT SCO Headset Mic to attached tag (just fiddling around) didn't work. I just happened to find this file while going the system files.
I am a noob with android and it system settings